# ExtJs cell editing

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs5

I have a grid with 3 columns and 5 rows.

I have attached a CellEditing plugin to the grid.
And for the 3rd column i have defined an numberfield editior.

So now due to this each row 3rd column has a  numberfield editor attached to it.

But due to some condition present in data/column metadata, i want to disable the numberfield editor for 2nd and 4th row.

I am unable to disable cell editor for particular rows as the editor is attached at the column level.

Is there a way in ExtJS to handle this kind of scenario.

I am using ExtJS 5.

Comment: Use the `beforeedit` event and return false for cells that are not editable.

Comment: Is there any other way doing that ? I don't want to use the beforeedit event. Basically i want to handle this when editor is attached to the cell.

Comment: No, because the editor is attached to the column and reused. The `beforeedit` event is where the editor is attached to the cell. Also, I'm curious why you say you don't want to use `beforeedit`, what makes you say that?

Comment: @EvanTrimboli i can use beforreedit to solve the scenario that i have.There is no specific reason that i dont want to use beforeedit, i just wanted to know whether there is any other way to handle it.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the comments by Evan, you need to use the [`beforeedit`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1.3/api/Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing.html#event-beforeedit) event to veto the edit before it starts.

ExtJS does not attach an editor to every cell. Instead, when the user triggers the edit (e.g. by single- or double-clicking on the grid cell), the CellEditing plugin will be invoked. *If* the `beforeedit` event is not vetoed, it will then attach the edit field to the cell in place. When the edit is finished, the edit field will be detached.

If you want to style the non-editable fields differently, to help indicate that they are not editable, the column can be assigned a [`renderer`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1.3/api/Ext.grid.column.Column.html#cfg-renderer), which will allow you to provide cell-specific attributes, including CSS style.